# Calculator shows syntax error and referenceError

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cost Calculator</title>
</head>
  <body>

    <h1>
        College Cost Calculator
    </h1>

    <form>
        <input type= "numbers" id= "annualCost" placholder= "annual cost" />
        <br>
        <input type= "numbers" id= "inflationRate" placholder= "inflationRate" />
        <br>
        <input type= "numbers" id= "yearsUntilCollege" placholder= "yearsUntilCollege" />
        <input id= "button" type="button" value = "Estimate" onclick= "calculator()"/>
        <input id= "reset" type="reset" value = "Reset"/>
    </form> 
    <p id= "result">

    </p>    

    <script>
      // your code here
        document.getElementById(button) = function calculator () {
       let inflationRate = document.getElementById(inflationRate);
        let annualCost = document.getElementById(annualCost);
        let totalCost;
        let annualSaving;
        let yearsUntilCollege = document.getElementById(yearsUntilCollege);
        totalCost = annualCost;
        let amount = (inflationRate * annualCost) + annualCost;
        totalCost += amount;
        amount = ((inflationRate * 2) * annualCost) + annualCost;
        totalCost += amount;
        amount = ((inflationRate * 3) * annualCost) + annualCost;
        totalCost += amount;
        annualSaving = totalCost / 5;
        return amount
        return annualSaving
        console.log(`For a 4 years college degree with Annual cost: $${annualCost} and Inflation rate: ${inflationRate}`);
        console.log(`You have to pay $${totalCost}.`);
        console.log(`You need to save ${annualSaving} annually for ${yearsUntilCollege} years.`)
        document.getElementById(result).innerHTMl = `For a 4 years college degree with Annual cost: $${annualCost} and Inflation rate: ${inflationRate}`
        `You have to pay $${totalCost}.`
        `You need to save ${annualSaving} annually for ${yearsUntilCollege} years.`
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a code to calculate the college cost for Four(04) years including inflation and how much to save before college begins.
Help me figure out the issue with this code. It keeps giving syntax Error 28:15 and reference Error. I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong and did I call the function correctly?

Comment: Lots of really basic errors in your JS code. For example, you can't have a bunch of things happen after your return statement because your return statement will end your function.

Answer (score 1):

Many issues here:

1- Element IDs are **strings**. Therefore, `document.getElementById` expects you to pass a string to it, and strings are surrounded by **quotation marks** (' or ").

2- To get the value of `<input>` elements, you should use `.value`. So for example:

```
//get the value of input with id "inflationRate"
var inflationRate = document.getElementById("inflationRate").value;
```

3- To call a function on button click, use the button's `onclick` event, like so:

```
function calculator() {
    //do something...
}
//call the function calculator whenever the button is clicked
document.getElementById("button").onclick = calculator;
```

4- As pointed out by @ecg8 in the comments, `return` statements **jump out of the function immediately**, and therefore you cannot have further statements/computations after the `return` statement, as they will not be reached.

And as a side note, in your HTML, numeric inputs should have a type of `number` and not `numbers`.

**Edit:** Also, in your last statement here:

```
document.getElementById(result).innerHTMl = `For a 4 years college degree with Annual cost: $${annualCost} and Inflation rate: ${inflationRate}`
        `You have to pay $${totalCost}.`
        `You need to save ${annualSaving} annually for ${yearsUntilCollege} years.`
```

To concatenate these three strings into one, either wrap the entire string (all the lines) into one pair of backticks (`), or use the `+` operator to concatenate the strings:

```
document.getElementById(result).innerHTMl = `For a 4 years college degree with Annual cost: $${annualCost} and Inflation rate: ${inflationRate}`
+ `You have to pay $${totalCost}.`
+ `You need to save ${annualSaving} annually for ${yearsUntilCollege} years.`;
```

---

> On a final note, all these issues are basic Javascript stuff, so I
>   would really recommend to study and understand the basics of
>   Javascript (syntax, functions, events, etc.) before solving problems
>   like this one.